# Ruby on Rails: create a relationship that combines three other relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to create a relationship that combines three other relationships. The initial three are all of the same class, I'd like like a conglomerate, however I can't find a nice "arel" way of doing it.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

The SQL query that works is

```
SELECT `records`.* FROM `records` INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `records`.`subject_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` OR `records`.`recorder_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` OR `records`.`subject_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` WHERE `memberships`.`group_id` = 4
```

Of course, I want to do that the rails way. Here is what I have so far. It should be pretty self-explanitory, so I won't waste your time explaining it further.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recorded_records, :through => :memberships, :source => :recorded_records, :class_name => "Record"
  has_many :reported_records, :through => :memberships, :source => :reported_records, :class_name => "Record"
  has_many :reviewed_records, :through => :memberships, :source => :reviewed_records, :class_name => "Record"

  #has_many :records through recorded_records, reported_records, reviewed_records??
  # Psuedo code above... Wondering how best to do this. I've tried...
  def records
    recorded_records | reported_records | reviewed_records
  end

  # But that makes three seperate database queries when what I really want is...
  # SELECT `records`.* FROM `records` INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `records`.`subject_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` OR `records`.`recorder_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` OR `records`.`subject_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` WHERE `memberships`.`group_id` = 4

end
```

You guys rock! Thanks :)

Comment: can you show the `Membership` model content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! Hey, thanks a lot for your help, @RiPuk. You spurred some thought on my point. What I did was create a view out of a select statement:

```
AS SELECT
  `records`.`id` AS `record_id`,
  `memberships`.`group_id` AS `group_id`
FROM (`records` join `memberships`) where ((`records`.`subject_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id`) or (`records`.`recorder_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id`) or (`records`.`subject_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id`));
```

I named this view `view_group_records`, then created an ActiveRecord model called GroupRecord (with the appropriate relationships) and now in my Group model, I set up a `has_many` relationship to GroupRecord, and then `has_many :records, :through => :group_records`.

This seems to work out well!

But your solution definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a custom join. Using your SQL above:

```
Record.joins('INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `records`.`subject_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` OR `records`.`recorder_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` OR `records`.`subject_membership_id` = `memberships`.`id` WHERE `memberships`.`group_id` = 4')
```

With a little work you could add this as a method within your model, make it accept parameters etc.

The Railsguide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) gives a few examples of using `.join`

Comment: Close! You mean `Record.joins`, I'll give this a shot and see how it works. Is there no way to do a relationship like this? With an "OR" multi-foreign-key?

Comment: Doh! Updated my answer. I can't see how you could do what you want with Rails and one query unless you do the custom join as above, and code a method around that. That's the beauty and the downside of Rails - convention over configuration :)